# Is there a way to find the implementation of methods with MethodImplOptions.InternalCall attribute?

Tags: decompilation, c#, game-hacking

**Background:**
The Unity engine provides a number of `PlayerPrefs.SetXxx` functions that can be used to save user data. However, it will automatically append a hash to the name of what you saved. For example, a call of
`PlayerPrefs.SetString("justTesting", "TEST!");` 
will add a registry value of
`justTesting_h3837386411`
on Windows platform.
**Problem:**
I know it's actually [djb2-xor](https://answers.unity.com/questions/177945/playerprefs-changing-the-name-of-keys.html), but I am still curious about how the hash function is implemented. By using dnSpy I found `PlayerPrefs.SetString`, which is implemented in `UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll`, finally calls a native method declared as

```
[NativeMethod("SetString")]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern bool TrySetSetString(string key, string value);
```

And I'm stuck here. There's indeed a string `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs::TrySetSetString` in `.rdata` section of `UnityPlayer.dll`, but I don't know where to find the actual code for it. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after some bold attempts I finally found it quite simple, at least on this Unity version.
First, find the method name string and where it's referenced:
[image]

It is referenced at 11376594. But what's at this address? Here we go:
[image]

It's a string table. The next thing to do is to find out the table's start address, and then what references to this address. This guided me here:
[image]
And here:
[image]
This is a loop, which binds each function name to items in another table at 11371C40. This new table is a function table so I renamed it:
[image]
Now it's reasonable to suspect this function table contains how each native method is implemented. By adding the string offset to the function table address, I got the `bool TrySetSetString(string key, string value)` address. Diving deeper and here is the hash algorithm:
[image]